# full justification not worked in tex studio

Tags: line-breaking, justification

[image: Document]

I want to write down this document in latex. It is a book type document. I am using this packages

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}              
\parindent0pt  \parskip10pt             
\raggedright                            
 \usepackage{listings}
```

As you can see that in right hand side lines are not in order.

How could I fix it?

Comment: your code fragment shows `\raggedright   ` so you get a ragged right margin

Comment: Unrelated to the line breaking but.. it is hard to tell from your image but you seem to be missing spaces after sentences:  "lots of data.Our.."  and "**friends**.This"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in comments